# image and text in div with border

Tags: html, css, image, text, border

Here is the code:

```
   <div  style="border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:1px;">

       <img src="some picture" align="left" /> 
       <div>
            <span >SOME TEXT</span></br>
            <span >SOME TEXT</span></br>
            <span >SOME TEXT</span>
       </div>  

   </div>
```

The span block takes less (vertical) space then image and so the border and image overlaps and the image is partly out of the div span. Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aTDYL/3/)

How to apply border to out div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clear the image and the div with spans adding : `<div style="clear:both"></div>` in the end.

```
<div  style="border-style:solid; border-color:aqua; border-width:3px;">

           <img id="image_HDDimageControl" src="http://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/beacon/t0193.jpg" align="left"> 
           <div>
             <span >SOME TEXT</span ></br>
             <span >SOME TEXT</span ></br>
             <span >SOME TEXT</span >
           </div>  

<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `overflow:auto` to the first div style.

Answer (score 2):

if this http://jsfiddle.net/vleran/aTDYL/8/ is what you are trying to do than just add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` before closing tag of the outer div (the parent div).